# Differential Equations: Substitution Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

$
(3x+y-2)dx + (3x+y+4)dy = 0
$

$
u = 3x + y
$

$
du = 3dx + dy
$

$
dy = du - 3dx
$


$
(u-2)dx + (u+4)(du - 3dx) = 0
$

$
(u+4)du + (u-2-3u-12)dx = 0
$

$
(u + 4)du + (-2u-14)dx=0
$

$
(u+4)du- (2u+14)dx=0
$
$$
\int{\left(\frac{u+4}{2u+14}\right)du} - \int{dx} =0
$$
$$
\int{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2u+14}\right)}du -\int{dx} =0     
$$
$$
(*)\frac{1}{2}\int{du}-3\int{\frac{du}{2u+14}} -\int{dx} =0  
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}u-\frac{3}{2} ln|2u+14|-x=c
$$

$
u-3ln|2u+14|-2x=c
$

$
(3x+y)-3ln|2(3x+y)+14|-2x=c
$

$
x+y-3ln|6x+2y+14|=c
$

**QUESTION:**

In step($*$), what if I factor out $2$ in $2u+14$. Then it will be...

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int{du}-\frac{3}{2}\int{\frac{du}{u+7}} -\int{dx} =0 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}u-\frac{3}{2} ln|u+7|-x=c
$$
$
u-3ln|u+7|-2x=c
$

$
(3x+y)-3ln|(3x+y)+7|-2x=c
$

$
x+y-3ln|3x+y+7|=c
$

Which is . . . 
$
[x+y-3ln|6x+2y+14|=c] \neq [x+y-3ln|3x+y+7|=c]
$

Is there something wrong in my solution? Or the second solution violate something? Please give me reasons. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, since $3\ln|6x+2y+14|=3\ln|2\cdot(3x+y+7)|=3\ln|3x+y+7|+c'$.

Comment: don't get it. ?

Comment: What is $\ln(ab)$, already?

Comment: $ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b) $ , then?

Comment: Then $a=2$, $b=|3x+y+7|$.

Comment: Okay I got it, since $ln (2)$ is a constant. Thanks